# Polite, non-profane equivalent to ‘kick a**’

Tags: american-english, offensive-language, colloquialisms

So, you have a web site to which you've posted a review stating "How to Kick Ass". This gets censored, which I can understand.

What's a very colloquial, not necessarily modern slang, easily recognizable equivalent to *kick ass*?

This review is in a military context.  The metric is, would it be inspiring for a graduation speech at West Point but also **easily recognizable** to a civilian? If it's a bit… colorful, then all the better. But it should be able to pass profanity filters.

**Clarification of the context.**

It's about a German WWII armored tactics history/handbook.  My original review title was going to be **'Kick Butt 103'** - I wanted to convey the sense that it was an impressive course to instill advanced organizational wisdom and experience, in this case on how to **dominate** your enemy.  Besides the title, my review goes into more details about how it is very much a 'how to' combat manual.  But I did want the title to be somewhat clear on its own.

Amazon wasn't keen on 'butt' however - which I thought a bit over the top.  Butt is colloquial, and colorful, but hardly obscene or profane.

**'Kick Ass 103'** would work as well.  But **'Trounce 103'** or **'Dominate 103'**, to take two good suggestions below, would, in my opinion, leave a reader rather puzzled as to what I was trying to say - about the only thing those two evoke are edgy website user names.  **Pown 103** might work, but that is gamer slang and might be too obscure to older readers.

Comment: Doesn't saying something *kicks butt* means it's good?

Comment: @RexYuan - from the "butt-kicker's" perspective? Certainly!

Comment: "butt" is offensive language? If "butt" is offensive, surely "behind", "rear", "rump", "posterior" would be "offensive" too?

Comment: Yeah, I always thought "kick butt" _was_ the (relatively) polite, non-profane equivalent.

Comment: chew bubblegum?

Comment: we say lambaste. as in, ohhh he lambasted him!

Comment: The Prez says "shellac"

Comment: There are no profanity filters here on SE (except that we bowdlerise profanities in titles): we encourage calling a spade a spade. I’ve un-bowdlerised your question and also made some minor edits to make it more readable—though I still don’t quite understand what you mean by “the metric is, would it be…”. I’m also not sure if you’re talking about _kicking ass_ in the sense of defeating someone (“I kicked his ass!”) or just in the sense of being generally awesome (“This PS3 kicks ass!”). You should clarify that, because the two make for very different answers.

Comment: @Duncan "Kick Bottom"

Comment: To calcitrate some derrière? Not as profane.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To "*kick butt*" is to "**Dominate**" or to "**Rule**!"

> [**Dominate**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=dominate+definition&gws_rd=ssl) *verb*: have a commanding influence on; exercise control over. "the company ***dominates*** the market for operating system software"
>
> ***synonyms***: control, influence, exercise control over, command, be in command of, be in charge of, rule, govern, direct, have ascendancy over, have mastery over.

(Google)

> [**Rule**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rules?s=t)
>   *verb*: to control or direct; exercise dominating power, authority, or influence over; govern: "to ***rule*** the empire with severity"

(Dictionary.com)

> [**Rule**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rule)
>   verb: to dominate; to be the best. (*Slang only in certain contexts*. Typical in graffiti.) "Pizza **rules** around here"
>
> **Rule the Roost** *informal* To be in charge; dominate: "In this house my parents ***rule the roost***"

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: I am going to go with **'Advanced Domination 103'**.  Close enough and evokes a university course even more so than my original title.

Comment: Thank you I. Philosopher, glad I could be of assistance.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosopher- Just be prepared to handle the people who show up with something entirely different in mind ;-)

Comment: I looked on Google but could not find what **103** means. I know **101** is AmEng for something that starts from scratch, a beginner's guide if you will, most often a school course, but *103* is what? The third year? Beta? sub-Microsoft? Help?!

Comment: errr, yes.  103 means advanced, as opposed to 101 basic.  many university courses have some variation on a numbering scheme starting at 101.  Or 1-2-3 also.

Answer (score 11):

I suggest **[Trounce](https://www.google.com/search?q=Trounce%20definition)** as meaning the same thing

> verb
>
> defeat heavily in a contest.
>  *"Essex trounced
>   Cambridgeshire 5–1 in the final"*
>  synonyms:   defeat utterly, beat
>   hollow, win a resounding victory over, annihilate, drub, rout, give
>   someone a drubbing, crush, overwhelm, bring someone to their
>   knees;
>
> rebuke or punish severely.
>  *"insider dealing has been
>   roundly trounced"*
>  synonyms:  thrash, beat, whip, flog, lash, birch,
>   cane, leather, spank, chastise, lambaste;

(Google)

Comment: "Trounce" is great, but I'd steer well clear of "lash", "birch", "leather" and especially "spank", all of which sound very old and British to my ear, and/or lend themselves to interpretations that are... probably more lascivious than what you're going for.  Also I often hear "X gave Y a drubbing", but I don't think I've ever heard "X drubbed Y".

Comment: @j_random_hacker Indeed. "How to Spank" would probably attract the wrong sort of audience. "How to Trounce" is less punchy than "How to Dominate" in my opinion but mainly for the ring of it. I just give it as another option that perhaps fulfills the 'a bit, colorful, all the better' secondary objective a bit better. That said, "How to Dominate" could attract the wrong sort of audience too ;)

Comment: @j_random_hacker - If you were a sports fan in the U.S., you'd hear this verb often. I found a quite a few samples in a Google search: _John Madden's 1976 Oakland Raiders drubbed the Minnesota Vikings 32-14 in Super Bowl XI to complete a 16-1 season; the Red Sox drubbed the White Sox 10-2 before one of Fenway's largest crowds of the year; The St. Louis Blues clinched a playoff spot Thursday when they drubbed the Calgary Flames; Old Dominion drubbed the Cavaliers at Davenport Field to the tune of a 14-5 blowout; the Seattle Seahawks drubbed the Denver Broncos, 43-8._

Comment: (That said, I completely agree with your advice to steer clear of "birch" and "spank". I think "thrash" seems okay, but I wouldn't use "chastise" in this context, either.)

Comment: I am a non native speaker with a fairly wide vocabulary, but I wouldn't have understood it. Something to consider if the audience is international. This said, I should start using this word!

Answer (score 2):

If it's addressed to an audience which can understand baseball metaphors, you can use "hit it out of the park".

Answer (score 2):

To [**cream**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cream):

> "... defeat (a person or team) easily and completely"

(Merriam-webster)

Comment: Please include a source attribution for your link and direct quotation.

Comment: The link isn't it's own source??

Comment: Hey there, Lamar. If the hypertext link becomes obsolete or suffers link-rot, then "cream" will lead nowhere. Additionally, direct quotations - as in the block-quote - require a source citation, in this case Merriam-Webster. You could kill two birds with one stone, by making the source citation your hypertext link, rather than your suggested term (cream). Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Makes sense - good tips :)   edit>> is my edit adequate, or is there a preferred format?

Comment: +1 Lamar - generally speaking, the more complete and self-sufficient your answer is, the more you regularly include incisive documentation drawn from established authority, examples of usage, links and source citations, the more positively your answer will be received and the more positive votes you will garner - all of which translates into rep points, which opens up features of the site not currently available to you at your rep level. Something to shoot for. Enjoy the site, and good night. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**[take them to the cleaners](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+to+the+cleaners) 103**

It has the same very colloquial feel as kick ass, and generally means the same thing but very safe. It may not be racey enough!

Answer (score 1):

For a military context I'd suggest "win", "winning", or 'victory".

- How to win
- Victory 103

And/or many [military units have mottos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_unit_mottoes_by_country) which presumably include some suitable words.

Answer (score 1):

If you need something close to "kick ass", but still slangy, a modern equivalent would be "pwn", pronounced like "own" with a "p" in front of it.  Variants include "pwnage" "uber pwnage", "totally pwned", etc.  You can find more uses by googling "pwn", or by playing a video game with a preteen.

In case you were wondering, "pwn" basically means "own", as in "I own you";  it boils down to saying you're much better than the other person.

An alternative, if your audience is a bit more clever, might be "We're all out of bubble gum". This comes from the movie "They Live", in which one character says "I came here to do two things:  kick ass and chew bubble gum. And I'm all out of bubble gum."

Less imaginatively, you could just switch "ass" with "tail", or spell "ass" as "@$$".

Comment: Sorry, -1 for promoting a typo ("pwn"). One can use the correct spelling, without changing the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ***beat*** as a non-profane, easy-to-understand, single-word alternative for your context.

There is also the phrasal verb ***beat up*** but it is used in literal sense mainly and things get physical. The video game genre [beat 'em up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_%27em_up) comes from there also.

> **beat:** Defeat (someone) in a game, competition, election, or commercial venture [*OD*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/beat)
>
> **beat up:** *(transitive)* To give a severe beating to. *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beat_up)*

---

- How to beat
- [How to beat up anything](http://www.howtobeatupanything.com/home/2010/12/how-to-beat-up-anything-the-book.html)

---

Also, the definition of *kick ass* in *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kick_ass)* agrees with me:

> *(idiomatic, US, Canada, colloquial)* To beat someone in a competition, fight, or other situation.

From *The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*
edited by Tom Dalzell, Terry Victor:

> **kick ass: 1** to be especially energetic and exciting; to succeed by your vigorous efforts. "Kick arse" and "kick butt" are common variations. *US, 1979.* **2** to use force, to beat up *US, 1962*.

As you can see, *beat* is closer to the first sense but *beat up* is closer to the second sense.

Comment: If "ass" and "butt" are unacceptable, the sexual slang meanings of "beat up" would probably also be unacceptable on the OP's site. If you are writing about German strategy, why not use a German term like "blitzkrieg"? I think that would be understood widely enough in British English, at least.

Comment: @alephzero: The problem is using the words "ass" and "butt", not "kick". *Beat* or *beat up* doesn't include profanity. There can be slang definitions of many polite words.

Comment: To "beat up" doesn't mean to win (i.e. beat an opponent), and it is not used in a "stronger sense" than *beat*. To [*beat someone up*](https://www.google.it/search?q=beat+someone+up&oq=beat+someone+up&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), means to use physical violence, to physically hurt a person; it is not used as a euphemism or metaphor.

Comment: I concur with @Mari-Lou assessment of "beat" and "beat up", on the other hand ermanen, "beat-*down*" is used figuratively, at least in the U.S., for  delivering a rather "decisive defeat."

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I improved my answer a bit. I thought OP was trying to combine both senses of *kick ass*. You are right that *beat up* is not figurative when used with indefinite pronouns.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for words/phrases that evoke a "let's go start a bar fight" type feeling, then the phrases **kicking ass** and **cracking skulls** are basically synonymous.  Cracking skulls may technically be less profane, but it does have a harsher tone to it; though that may suit your needs for the word just fine (example below)

> "Here is your textbook cadets,
>   Zie-Lengthy-Original-German-Titled-Armor-Tactics-Manual, or as you
>   will lovingly come to refer to it **Skull Cracking 101**."

Answer (score -1):

To kick a** is to "wreck shop."

To my judgment, the best example of the latter term comes from the song "Mama Said Knock You Out," by LL Cool J:

> Explosion, overpowerin'
>
> Over the competition, I'm towerin'
>
> **Wreckin' shop**, when I drop
>
> These lyrics that'll make you call the cops

Comment: It is unhelpful to define one slang term solely with another slang term.  In any case "wreck shop" is inapt for the usage "This barbecue sauce is kick ass!"

Comment: @deadrat the OP has asked for slang equivalent to "kick a**," used as a verb.  i have answered the OP's question.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to give a full explanation of how it would fit.